# How to round large double values received by conversion from byte array?

Tags: c#

I have an array of bytes which I'm parsing like this:

```
void FormatInput(byte[] bytes)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length - 4; i = i + 4)
    {
        Output.Text += BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes, i) + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

After parsing I receive values similar to this:

2,17480386561496E-306, -5,47880675480372E+99, 3,1483818683805E-304, 7,62967345850305E-317 ...

**How can I round these values to two decimals?**

I'm receiving data from BLE device (Arduino sensor). Sending method looks like this:

*static void write(float&, float&, float&, float&, float&).*

Data of interest for client app is contained in first two floats of this data load.

On the client side I receive byte[20] for 5 floats sent from BLE device. I have split my incoming byte array into 5 chunks of 4 bytes and took first two in order to parse them to float.

```
void FormatInput(byte[] bytes)
{
    var arraysOf4Bytes = bytes
        .Select((b, i) => new { b, i })
        .GroupBy(x => x.i / 4)
        .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.b)
        .ToArray())
        .ToList();

    foreach (var item in arraysOf4Bytes.Take(2))
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            var data = BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? item.Reverse().ToArray() : item, 0);
            Output.Text += data.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result of my 5 chunks.

[image]

However I'm still getting huge values after parsing. Expected values after parsing should be in the range between 0 and 100.

Comment: By using `Math.Round`

Comment: just format them for printing with `.ToString("G3")` or some other format you want

Comment: Are you certain that the `Byte[] bytes` you're working with _actually contain_ IEEE-754 values?

Comment: use this regular expression/substitution `(\d,\d{2}).*E(.*)`  (https://regex101.com/r/OiD816/1), but it will not round...

Comment: @Dai yes, this is actually my problem, I have tried with Math.Round; ToString("G3"), but I'm always ending up with E+-XXX

Comment: @user3569465 Where are you getting this data from? ...and **exactly** what IEEE-754 serialization scheme is it using? What about endianess?

Comment: These are very large numbers.. If you  are sure the data is correct rounding them anyhow will remove rather large values. If you still insist - I'd simply convert to string and cut out part of it.

Comment: I bet it's every second one that is messed up, right?  I see now that `i = i + 4` is the problem.  A double is 8 bytes.

Comment: I have updated my question with more detailed informations.

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by _huge_. In addition, please post (a) values actually passed to the sending method, and (b) output of your corrected algorithm calling `ToSingle()`.

Answer (score 2):

The `double` data type occupies *8 bytes*, not 4. Hence, to convert into `double`, you have to increment by 8:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length - 8; i = i + 8)
{
    Output.Text += BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes, i) + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

All this provided in the `bytes` array there are actual `double`s serialized in the correct binary format.

If the values are *4-byte* floating-point numbers, hence the `float` data type, then fix the data type and use the [`BitConverter.ToSingle()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.tosingle?view=net-6.0%5D) instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length - 4; i = i + 4)
{
    Output.Text += BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, i) + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

*Note: Ideally eliminate the hard-coded constants and use `sizeof(double)` / `sizeof(float)` instead of `8` / `4`.*